# How to add data into MSQL database by using c# programming?

Tags: c#

Good day!
Using visual studio 2012, I have created a Student class with get and set codes, and i need to complete the StudentDAO class to create insert coding that will use to store data to database student table. this action is perform by a windows form button click event.

what i need to create a **button click code** and then **insert into database code**,

//Student.cs class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace SRSJason
{

class Student
{
    private string S_Student_id;
    private string S_Full_name;
    private DateTime S_Dob;
    private string S_Address;
    private int S_Contact;
    private string S_Username;
    private string S_Password;


    public Student()        //Default constructor
    {

    }

    public Student(string Student_id, string Full_name, DateTime Dob, string Address, int Contact, string Username, string Password)  //Overloadign
    {
        S_Student_id = Student_id;
        S_Full_name = Full_name;
        S_Dob = Dob;
        S_Address = Address;
        S_Contact = Contact;
        S_Username = Username;
        S_Password = Password;
    }

    public void setID(string Student_id)
    {
        S_Student_id = Student_id;
    }
    public string getID()
    {
        return S_Student_id;
    }

    public void setName(string Full_name)
    {
        S_Full_name = Full_name;
    }
    public string getName()
    {
        return S_Full_name;
    }

    public void setDob(DateTime Dob)
    {
        S_Dob = Dob;
    }
    public DateTime getDob()
    {
        return S_Dob;
    }

    public void setAddress(string Address)
    {
        S_Address = Address;
    }
    public string getAddress()
    {
        return S_Address;
    }

    public void setContact(int Contact)
    {
        S_Contact = Contact;
    }
    public int getContact()
    {
        return S_Contact;
    }

    public void setUsername(string Username)
    {
        S_Username = Username;
    }
    public string getUsername()
    {
        return S_Username;
    }

    public void setPassword(string Password)
    {
        S_Password = Password;
    }
    public string getPassword()
    {
        return S_Password;
    }




}
```

}`

//StudentDAO class (please help me to complete this code)

```
`class StudentDAO
{
    static string constring = "Data Source=JAZE;Initial Catalog=srsjason;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection m_con = new SqlConnection(constring);


}`
```

//button click from the form (please help me to complete this code as well)

```
private void submitstudent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

please help me to complete this coding

Comment: http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all when you create private properties u cant access them in your forms, you have to create a method instead inside the same class then use it in your form. second you should know about the `ORM - Object Relational Mapping` that you are using.

Here I'll list them:

- [ADO.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [LINQ to SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [ADO.NET Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx)

When you picked one of those. next step would be learning about how they work and whats the syntax.

However knowing that you kinda showed a syntax of `ADO.NET` Here is an Example how you can insert the data in your data base using ADO.NET. If you want to add data directly from code-behind without a method. so basically on click event of your button.

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
   //create  object  of Connection Class..................
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

   // Set Connection String property of Connection object..................
  con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=KUSH-PC;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated           Security=True";

 // Open Connection..................
  con.Open();

 //Create object of Command Class................
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

//set Connection Property  of  Command object.............
cmd.Connection = con;
//Set Command type of command object
//1.StoredProcedure
//2.TableDirect
//3.Text   (By Default)

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

//Set Command text Property of command object.........

cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Registration (Username, password) values ('@user','@pass')";

//Assign values as `parameter`. It avoids `SQL Injection`
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", TextBox1.text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pass", TextBox2.text);

       //Execute command by calling following method................
  //1.ExecuteNonQuery()
       //This is used for insert,delete,update command...........
  //2.ExecuteScalar()
       //This returns a single value .........(used only for select command)
  //3.ExecuteReader()

      //Return one or more than one record.
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();


  MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");          
  }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            con.Close();
     }


    }
```

Be sure that you've included your `ConnectionString` in your `config` file.

Comment: @RichardJSimmons no problem:)